# How do I play the raid horn sound in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I make the raid horn sound play in Minecraft Bedrock?

Comment: What do you mean with "make the sound"?

Comment: @Joachim you know the horn that plays when a raid comes? I think he means he wants to play the horn sound with commands

Comment: @Penguin I think so too, but that should be explicated in the question.

Comment: You can actually play the sound using a goat horn, but that's in the Bedrock Edition Beta.

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
/playsound raid.horn @a
```

This will play the horn sound for everyone in the world.